# Custom image datagenerator (keras) extremely slow due to converting list of numpy arrays into single array

Tags: arrays, performance, numpy, keras, image-segmentation

I've got a bottleneck in the training of my neural model. I have written a custom generator that loads both images and masks on the fly to pass to my model for training. I found that even when I was using a gpu it was extremely slow and narrowed this down to when I convert my batch of masks from a list of arrays into an array with dimensions (batch, height, width, classes). This seems to be taking a long time, however, I can't work out why? Each mask is 224x224x4 (4 classes as its been one-hot-encoded) and i'm only using a batch of 16. If I generate a list of a random set of (224x224x4) arrays and apply the np.array(arrays) operation to them it is extremely quick.  Any ideas would be appreciated?

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from skimage import img_as_bool
from skimage.transform import resize


class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, imgIds, maskIds, imagePath, maskPath, weights=[1,1,1,1],
                        batchSize=16, shuffle=False):
        self.imgIds = imgIds
        self.maskIds = maskIds
        self.imagePath = imagePath
        self.maskPath = maskPath
        self.weights = np.array(weights)
        self.batchSize = batchSize
        self.shuffle = shuffle


    '''
    for each image id load the patch and corresponding mask
    '''
    def __load__(self, imgName, maskName):

        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(self.imagePath,imgName))
        img = img/255.0

        mask = np.load(os.path.join(self.maskPath,maskName))
        mask = np.multiply(mask, self.weights)
        mask = tf.cast(mask, tf.float32)

        return (img, mask)


    '''
    get the files for each batch (override __getitem__ method)
    '''
    def __getitem__(self, index):

        if(index+1)*self.batchSize > len(self.imgIds):
            self.batchSize = len(self.imgIds) - index*self.batchSize

        batchImgs = self.imgIds[self.batchSize*index:self.batchSize*(index+1)]
        batchMasks = self.maskIds[self.batchSize*index:self.batchSize*(index+1)]
        batchfiles = [self.__load__(imgFile, maskFile) for imgFile, maskFile in zip(batchImgs, batchMasks)]
        images, masks = zip(*batchfiles)

        return np.array(list(images)), np.array(list(masks))


    '''
    Return number of steps per batch that are needed (override __len__ method)
    '''
    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.imgIds)/self.batchSize))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do as much as you can in `tensorflow` (I'm using `tensorflow 2.1.0`):

```
def __load__(self, imgName, maskName):
  path = os.path.join(self.imagePath,imgName)
  img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.io.read_file(path)))
  img = img/255.0
  mask = np.load(os.path.join(self.maskPath,maskName))
  mask = tf.cast(mask, tf.float32)
  mask = tf.multiply(mask, self.weights)
```

`np.multiply` is definitely a bad idea, for sure user `tf.multiply`. I worry about`np.load`, and that it might be slow as well, as your data is not at all compressed (meaning more I/O).

You can fix the `np.load` issue by using a `tf.data.TFRecord` to save your data, and use a `tf.data.Dataset` as your data generator. This is the goto way for performance on loading data in `tensorflow`.

Comment: I will definitely make these changes, however, my bottleneck seems to be at the point of np.array(list(masks)) but I don't know why. I would have thought calling the array operation on 64 (224,224,4) arrays would not be that computationally expensive

Comment: `zip` is a generator, so when you call `list(mask)s` only then your list gets materialized. try surrounding every `zip` with a `list` call, and do your timings again, it will give you a better idea of where your actual bottleneck is.

Comment: On the tf.data.TFRecord do you have any good resources? I have found some nice explanations but want to know how to integrate with keras generator

Comment: hmm - it's more of an "or" situation (as in either use a `tf.data.Dataset` or a keras generator). It in itself is a data generator (it lazily loads the data). I don't see any reason to wrap it into a keras data generator but I thinks it's pretty easy. I'll post some pseudo code as an answer, that way it's better formatted.

Comment: If you're going to use `tf.data.Dataset` there's no reason to use a `keras generator`  anymore. Wrapping it in there is not really useful, but possible. `__init__` creates the `tf.data.Dataset`, `__load__` is empty, `__len__` just loops over the entire dataset to count it (`count = sum([1 for i in self.tf_dataset]`) and `__get_item__` just returns `self.tf_dataset.next()`

Comment: Ok so once I read and parse the TFRecords using tf.data.Dataset I will pass them to the keras (sin ce I am using keras for model compilation and training( model.fit method. I have generated the TFRecords so will have a go at reading them and see where I get to